# Trying to get a REACT img to appear

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am using a `js` script to store information to insert into a REACT portfolio.
I have a file named `info.js` and a section in here looks like

```
let info = { portfolio: [
      {
         name: "this app",
         description: "this app does this",
         imgurl: "images/this_app.jpg",
         url: "https://urlhere.com"
     }]
 }
```

I have my images in a folder like `src/images/`.
I am able to get the app name, description and `a` tag to render, but I cannot get the image to show up.
Here is what I have in my `js` script

```
export default class Portfolio extends Component { 
   render () {
     let Info = this.props.info;
     return (
        <div>
           {Info.portfolio && Info.portfolio.map((item) => {
              return (
                <div>
                    <img src={`${item.imgurl}`} alt="" />
                    <a href=`${item.url}`}>
                    <h5> {`${item.name}`}</h5>
                    </a>
                    <p>{item.description}</p>
                </div>
             );
          })};
      );
   }
}
```

So I think the `imgurl` in the portfolio array is wrong, but I'm not sure how to link that in there for each image.

Answer (score 0):

Static files should be in `public` folder not in `src`, and other thing is that the url should start with `/` like this. `/images/this_app.jpg"`.

So, move your `images` folder to `public` and fix the url.

Comment: I moved the ```images``` into the ```public``` folder and now the imgurl is ```imgurl: "/images/this_app.jpg"```. The image still is not showing up in ```localhost:```.

Comment: you moved the images into public, or moved the images into a filder called images in public folder ?

Comment: My folders are as follows now:   ```public/images``` and then I have ```src/components``` - so I moved the entire image folder into public folder (images are in images folder)

Answer (score 0):

In react, you need to import the image into the file where it is rendered.
So to use an image, you would have to use

`import image from ./image.png`

and then you could render, it, like so

`<img src={image}/>`

The official documentation is here

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/

Comment: But if I'm using ```map``` to get each item and its image, how do I ```import``` each image and render them?

Comment: Not tested, but try making an array of images and importing the array?

Comment: If I import like ```import image from "../../public/images";``` then I get the following error at ```npm start``` : ```You attempted to import ../../public/images which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.```